# CursorLoader not updating after data change

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

I have created a small application, trying to understand the functionality of the `LoaderManager` and `CursorLoader`-classes.

I have implemented `LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` on my `FragmentActivity`-class and everything works fine, except the fact that when I update my data via `ContentResolver.update()` or `ContentResolver.insert()`-methods, `onLoadFinished()` is not called and as a result my data doesn't update.

I have a custom ContentProvider and I am wondering if the problem is in my ContentProvider not notifying that the data changed or something else.

Comment: do you call `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri,..);` in your update/insert ContentProvider methods implementation ? do you call `cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);` before return it from query method in your ContentProvider

Comment: Nope, I didn't, that was the problem! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Did you call `setNotificationUri(ContentResolver cr, Uri uri)` on the `Cursor` before returning it in `ContentProvider.query()`?

And did you call `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null)` in the 'insert' method of your `ContentProvider`?

EDIT:

To get a `ContentResolver` call `getContext().getContentResolver()` in your `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!Seems like this is the problem, how can I get a ContentResolver from the ContentProvider to put it in setNotificationUri()?

EDIT: I found it, just use getContext().getCntentProvider()

Comment: Annoying that this isn't mentioned when I followed the [android dev docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) to create a content provider

Comment: Also, you should NOT call cursor.close() at ANY point in onLoadFinished else you will not receive any further updates to the underlying dataset.

Comment: Does the URI passed to the setNotificationUri() match that of the notifyChange() URI exactly, or does simply have to have the same authority or something?

Comment: The URIs have to be equal.

Comment: YES, YES, YES!! Wish I'd seen this Q&A 24 hours ago - but still very happy to have finally got this nailed!

Comment: @Herrmann Is there something else one should be aware of. Namely: I call both setNotificationUri(ContentResolver cr, Uri uri) and notifyChange(uri, null) with the same URI. Yet my list view is not updated.

Comment: Hmm, do you use a custom cursor? Have you implemented a ContentProvider?

Comment: @Herrmann Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741634/how-to-make-notifychange-work-between-two-activities.

Comment: And you should use getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null) whenever you update your data. I mean insert update delete.

Answer (score 5):

Also check if you call somewhere cursor.close(), because in this case you unregister the content observer which was registered by CursorLoader. And the cursor closing is managed by CursorLoader.

Comment: This was the missing link in my implementation

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer was the little bit tricky to understand so I am writing the answer to make it easy for other developers..

1. Go to the class in which you have extended the `ContentProvider`
2. Find the query() method which has the following syntax

   `public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)`
3. Write this line where you are returning the cursor

   `cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;`

In the end, my query method looks like this

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = noticeDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
            NoticeContract.NoticeTable.TABLE_NAME,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
    );
    //This line will let CursorLoader know about any data change on "uri" , So that data will be reloaded to CursorLoader
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}`
```