# Refresh ListView from ListActivity with CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity, listadapter, android-cursoradapter

I have a ListActivity that uses a CursorAdapter, and I can't get it to refresh. Here is some of the code I'm using:

```
public class ContactDetailsActivity extends ListActivity
{

    private ContactDetailsBroadcastReceiver mLvBroadcastReceiver;
    private Contact contact;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        contact = (Contact)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(AwesomeApp.CONTACT_OBJECT);

        if(contact == null) {
            DataUtils.log("Starting ContactDetailsActivity with NULL contact.");
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_contact_selected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        DataUtils.log("Starting ContactDetailsActivity with contact:" + contact.toString());
        setTitle(contact.getName());

        Cursor cursor = getContactDetailsCursor();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        setListAdapter(new ContactDetailsCursorAdapter(this, cursor));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Toast.makeText(ContactDetailsActivity.this, "touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //Create broadcast receiver, to detect when a file upload has finished so we can update the pic status.
        mLvBroadcastReceiver = new ContactDetailsBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    private class ContactDetailsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            DataUtils.log("In BroadcastReceiver - ContactDetails");
            refreshListView();
        }
    }
```

My adapter basically just extends `CursorAdapter` in which I override `newView` and `bindView`:

```
public class ContactDetailsCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter
```

I have a method inside `ContactDetailsActivity` called `refreshListView()` which I call in `onResume()`, and in the `onReceive()` method of my BroadcastReceiver

```
private void refreshListView()
{
    DataUtils.log("In ContactDetailsActivity refreshListView");
    ((ContactDetailsCursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

    this.getListView().invalidate();

    this.getListView().invalidateViews();
}
```

This is my `getContactDetailsCursor()` method:

```
private Cursor getContactDetailsCursor()
{
    AwesomeDbAdapter dbAdapter = AwesomeApp.getDbAdapter(this);
    Cursor c = dbAdapter.getRecentConversationsFromContact(contact.getId());
    DataUtils.log("New ContactDetails cursor has " + c.getCount() + " elements");
    return c;
}
```

As you can see, I've tried `notifyDataSetChanged()`, `invalidate()`, `invalidateViews()` and nothing seems to refresh the listview.

I'm totally out of ideas on how to get this to refresh. I'm seeing the logs and the method is being called both from `onResume()` and from the BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive()` methods.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked for me. As mentioned by @Kirill Shalnov, `startManagingCursor()` is deprecated however it's what I need to use. To be honest it's all a bit of guesswork, but alas does what I need.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void refreshListView()
{
    DataUtils.log("In ContactDetailsActivity refreshListView");

    ContactDetailsCursorAdapter adapter = (ContactDetailsCursorAdapter)getListAdapter();

    Cursor oldCursor = null;
    if(adapter != null) {
        oldCursor = adapter.getCursor();
    }
    Cursor newCursor = getContactDetailsCursor();

    if(oldCursor != null) {
        stopManagingCursor(oldCursor);
        oldCursor.close();
    }
    startManagingCursor(newCursor);

    adapter = null;
    setListAdapter(new ContactDetailsCursorAdapter(this, newCursor));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
    listView.invalidate();
    listView.invalidateViews();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you forgot to register the receiver:
Register the receiver without registering it won't fire, register that receiver like below.

Example:
In OnCreate:

```
ContactDetailsBroadcastReceiver receiver=new ContactDetailsBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE")
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

In OnDestroy:

```
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

Comment: Actually it is being registered and I see the log message when `onReceive()` method is called and `refreshListView()` is called. But the listview remains the same. This code wasn't included above for clarity, but this is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> startManagingCursor(cursor);

It is deprecated way to work with cursor, you should to use [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), which can reload data automatically

Comment: In addition to this, my data is only used by my application, and as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326954/how-to-read-an-sqlite-db-in-android-with-a-cursorloader it seems Loaders are more suited for ContentProvider data and not so much for other data not provided in this way.

Comment: Loaders is solution to async loading cursor from data, for example, by using SQL, no matter did you use ContentProvider or not

Comment: @Sandy so, are you sure "notifyDataSetChanged()" should to requery cursor? I think that this method just initiate redrawing of listview with current cursor, and you have to requery data manually

Comment: I tried with a new cursor, via swapCursor, with no avail.

Comment: Could you attach your getContactDetailsCursor(); implementation?

Comment: @Sandy may it can help - update your cursor into  adapter - adapter.getCursor().requery(); in the refresh method or try to adapter.swapCursor(newCursor); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();