# CursorLoader not updating after notifyChange call

Tags: android

I have registered a `CursorLoader`, but it is not receiving updates from my `ContentProvider`

The sequence of events is:

1. In a `Fragment`, register the CursorLoader with:

   ```
   getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_FAVS_ID, null, this);
   ```

   Note I am using the support library version ,so this method is `android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getLoaderManager()`
2. The `CursorLoader` is registered, and a `Cursor` is loaded in the `onLoadFinished`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
           Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished");
           switch (loader.getId()) {
           case LOADER_FAVS_ID:
                   Log.i(TAG,
                                   "cursor notification uri: " + cursor.getNotificationUri());
                   mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
                   break;
           }
   }
   ```

   Which Logs `cursor notification uri: content://com.myapp.mylocation/db_locations`, for example.  This is because I made sure to call `cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);` before returning the Cursor from my ContentProvider.
   Also note that my content provider returns a `MergeCursor`.
3. Some time later, a call is made to `update()` in my `ContentProvider`, and the following lines are executed:

   ```
   Log.i(TAG,
           "Notifying uri: " + uri.toString());
   getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(
           uri, null);
   ```

   Which Logs `Notifying loc uri: content://com.myapp.mylocation/db_locations`, the same uri as above.

But `onLoadFinished` is never called, and my `Cursor` is never updated. I believe I have followed the advice I can find, all of which is basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915050/cursorloader-not-updating-after-data-change). Why else would `onLoadFinished` not be called after all of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it, but since I haven't seen this documented, here's my solution.

I was returning a `MergeCursor` from my `ContentProvider`, basically just concatenating a list of cursors. I had

```
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
            // Generate an array of Cursors

            MergeCursor mergCursor = new MergeCursor(cursorArray);

            // notify potential listeners
            mergCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

            return mergCursor;
    }
```

And my `CursorLoader` was never receiving the notification. However, as `MergeCursor` is basically just an Array of `Cursor`, you need to set the notification uri on **each** cursor in your `MergeCursor`.

```
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
            // Generate an array of Cursors

            // set the notification uris...
            for (Cursor cursor : cursorArray) {
                    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            }

            MergeCursor mergCursor = new MergeCursor(cursorArray);

            return mergCursor;
    }
```

Now everything works as expected!