# content resolver notifyChange() not working

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have setup a fragment to pull data from a custom content provider using a CursorLoader.

The problem is that when i update a record in the SQLite table using the content resolver, the cursor does not refresh i.e. the `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(myUri, null)` has no effect. I have to exit the fragment and open it again to see the change.

I think the problem is that the URI i have used to update a row is not being observed by the loader :

- URI to create loader -`content://com.myapp.provider/MyTable/Set/22`
- URI to update row -`content://com.myapp.provider/MyTable/167`

167 identifies a unique row in the table. 22 identifies a set of rows in the table. *Is there some way to tell the loader that the row 167 comes within the set 22, so it should reset the cursor?*

Here is the code in case it brings more clarity :

**Creating CursorLoader in Fragment :**

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle queryBundle) {
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Uri.parse("content://com.myapp.provider/MyTable/Set/22"), myProjection, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}
```

**on button click in fragment :**

```
mContext.getContentResolver().update("content://com.myapp.provider/MyTable/167", values, null, null);
```

**Content Provider class :**

```
private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.myapp.provider";
private static final String TABLE_PATH = "MyTable";
public static final String CONTENT_URI_BASEPATH = "content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + TABLE_PATH;

private static final int URITYPE_TABLE = 1;
private static final int URITYPE_SINGLE_SET = 2;
private static final int URITYPE_SINGLE_ROW = 3;

private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static{
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_PATH,URITYPE_TABLE);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_PATH + "/Set/#", URITYPE_SINGLE_SET);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_PATH + "/#", URITYPE_SINGLE_ROW);
    }

@Override
public int update(Uri myUri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs){
    int rowCount = 0;
    String id;
    SQLiteDatabase db = localDB.getWritableDatabase();
    int uriType = sUriMatcher.match(myUri);

    switch(uriType){
    case URITYPE_SINGLE_ROW :
    id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        //selection and selectionArgs are ignored since the URI itself identifies a unique row. 
        rowCount = db.update(MyTable.TABLE_NAME, values, MyTable.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] {id});
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(myUri, null);
    return rowCount;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to call `notifyChange()` on the Uri that is being observed i.e. the set and not on the row.

To achieve this, we need to make some changes :

1. Include the set ID in the URI when calling the update :

   ```
   mContext.getContentResolver().update("content://com.myapp.provider/MyTable/Set/22/167", values, null, null);
   ```
2. Change the URI pattern of a single row from "/#" to "/Set/#/#"

   ```
   private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
   static{
   sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_PATH,URITYPE_TABLE);
   sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_PATH + "/Set/#", URITYPE_SINGLE_SET);
   sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_PATH + "/Set/#/#", URITYPE_SINGLE_ROW);
   }
   ```
3. Then in the update function, construct a new Uri that has to be notified :

   ```
   List<String> pathSegments = uri.getPathSegments();
   String mySetID = pathSegments.get(2); 
   Uri mySetUri = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + TABLE_PATH + "/Set/" + mySetID);
   getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(mySetUri, null);
   ```

Answer (score 6):

I has a similar issue and found the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915050/cursorloader-not-updating-after-data-change).

In brief, it turned out I needed to call `setNotificationUri(ContentResolver cr, Uri uri)` on the cursor returned by the `query()` method of my content provider.