# How to refresh Android Files app directory view on DocumentsProvider data

Tags: android, documents-provider

I have a `DocumentsProvider` that simply republishes a directory from an external file storage. Everything works well, however when deleting a file from the Android Files application, the directory does not get refreshed after the file is deleted. I'm probably supposed to call `contentResolver.notifyChange`, but I'm struggling to find the proper content uri.

```kotlin
@Throws(FileNotFoundException::class)
override fun deleteDocument(documentId: String) {
    val file = getFileForDocId(documentId)
    if (!file.delete()) {
        throw FileNotFoundException("Failed to delete document with id $documentId")
    }
    // Notify parent about directory change
    file.parentFile?.let { parent ->
        val parentDocId = getDocIdForFile(parent)
        val updatedUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUri(
                BuildConfig.FILES_AUTHORITY, parentDocId)
        context!!.contentResolver.notifyChange(updatedUri, null)
    }
}
```

I tried many combinations with the Uri, but it still doesn't work. I even tried to make all the identifiers in URL lowercase, no luck. The only thing that seemed to have at least some effect was trying to refresh the `root` - it forced `queryRoots`.
Deleting the file on the Google Drive seems to trigger the proper refresh, so there is probably some way.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27583807/149901

When returning a `Cursor` from the query methods, the `setNotificationUri` method must be used with the proper uri. Then the `notifyChange` works correctly.