# Android ListFragment data not updating via SimpleCursorAdapter / LoaderManager / notifyChange()

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment, simplecursoradapter, android-loadermanager

I have a ListFragment that shows the names of all the shopping lists stored in my database table.

The problem is that when I add a new shopping list row to the table, the ListFragment on the UI is not automatically updated. (The change can only be seen if I close and restart the app.)

Firstly, this is the code that is executed in my `DbContentProvider` class when I add a shopping list:

`

```
            // Insert the values into the table
            id = db.insert(SHOPPING_LISTS_META_TABLE, null, values);

            if (id > -1) {
                // Construct and return the URI of the newly inserted row.
                Uri insertedId = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI_SHOPPING_LISTS_META, id);

                // Notify any observers of the change in the data set.
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "................. notifyChange(\"" + insertedId + "\", null)");
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(insertedId, null);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "................. notifyChange() done");
                return insertedId;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
```

`

...and here is the LogCat output for it...

`10-28 12:29:41.133: D/SQLiteOpenHelper(19401): ................. notifyChange("content://org.example.myapp.DbContentProvider/shopping_lists_meta/12", null)
10-28 12:29:41.143: D/SQLiteOpenHelper(19401): ................. notifyChange() done
10-28 12:29:41.153: D/HomeActivity(19401): Shopping list, "My Test Shopping List" created: content://org.example.myapp.DbContentProvider/shopping_lists_meta/12
10-28 12:29:41.183: D/AbsListView(19401): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-28 12:29:41.193: E/ViewRootImpl(19401): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
10-28 12:29:41.503: D/AbsListView(19401): unregisterIRListener() is called`

In LogCat, there is **no output at all** from my ListFragment class when I add the new shopping list row. Here is my ListFragment class...

`

public class ShoppingListNamesListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks {

```
private final static String LOG_TAG = ShoppingListNamesListFragment.class.getSimpleName(); 

// This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data
public static SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

// These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve
static final String[] PROJECTION = {DbContentProvider.KEY_ID,
    DbContentProvider.KEY_SHOPPING_LIST_NAME,
    DbContentProvider.KEY_IS_SHOPPING_LIST_SELECTED};

// This is the select criteria
static final String SELECTION = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "................. onCreate()");

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "................. onActivityCreated()");

    // For the cursor adapter, specify which columns go into which views
    String[] fromColumns = {DbContentProvider.KEY_SHOPPING_LIST_NAME};
    int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1}; // The TextView in simple_list_item_1

    // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
    // We pass null for the cursor, then update it in onLoadFinished()
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(), 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
            fromColumns, toViews, 0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
    // or start a new one.
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "................. onCreateView()");
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

// Called when a new Loader needs to be created
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "................. onCreateLoader()");
    // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
    // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), DbContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_SHOPPING_LISTS_META,
            PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);

}

// Called when a previously created loader has finished loading
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "................. onLoaderFinished()");
    // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
    // old cursor once we return.)
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);      
}

// Called when a previously created loader is reset, making the data unavailable
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "................. onLoaderReset()");
    // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
    // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
    // longer using it.
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);      
}

@Override 
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    makeToast("shopping list clicked: " + position);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "shopping list clicked: " + position);
}

private void makeToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

NB - In my `DbContentProvider` class, I have...

`public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_SHOPPING_LISTS_META = Uri.parse("content://org.example.myapp.DbContentProvider/shopping_lists_meta");
public static final String SHOPPING_LISTS_META_TABLE = "shopping_lists_meta";`

I have based my code on [this Android ListFragment / LoaderManager example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html). And none of the similar questions to this that I have found offer a solution that fixes my problem.

I am fairly new to Android, so it could be a simple mistake I've made. But, essentially, it seems to me that when `notifyChange()` is called in my `DbContentProvider` class, my ListFragment is not being notified (or there is some other error in this area). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours and hours on this, I created a TestListActivity that hooked up to the native Contacts content provider - and that all worked/updated as it should, so I knew the issue was probably in my own content provider that I'd written.

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915050/cursorloader-not-updating-after-data-change). Turns out I had not called `setNotificationUri(ContentResolver cr, Uri uri)` on the `cursor` returned by the `query()` method of my content provider. (I'm sure this was never mentioned in the Reto Mauer book I was working from...) :/

Anyway, all sorted now! :)