# CursorLoader doesn't update contents

Tags: android, sqlite, uri, android-cursorloader

I have a ContentProvider. There are my query and insert methods:

```
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    long id = -1;
    switch (match) {
        case ARTICLES_LIST:
            id = ArticlesDataSource.getInstance().addArticle(values);
            break;
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Notify change for URI: " + uri);
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    if (id != -1) {
        return ArticleContract.buildArticleWithIdUri(id);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and

```
 @Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    Cursor refCursor = null;
    switch (match) {

        case ARTICLES_LIST:
            refCursor = ArticlesDataSource.getInstance().getAllPreviewArticlesCursor(selectionArgs, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
            break;

        case ARTICLES_LIST_BY_CATEGORY:
            Article.Category category = ArticleContract.getCategoryFromUri(uri);
            refCursor = ArticlesDataSource.getInstance().getPreviewArticlesCursorByCategory(selectionArgs, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder, category);

            //Modify uri for correct listener behaviour. Full uri is: content://payspace.ssidit.pp.ua.payspacemagazine/articles/category/categoryName
            List<String> segments = uri.getPathSegments();
            String lastSegment = segments.get(segments.size() - 2);
            String uriStr = uri.toString();
            uri = Uri.parse(uriStr.substring(0, uriStr.indexOf(lastSegment) - 1));
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknwon uri: " + uri);
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Registered for observe changes in uri: " + uri.toString());
    refCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return refCursor;
}
```

My logs for notifyChange() and setNotificationUri():

*Registered for observe changes in uri: content://payspace.ssidit.pp.ua.payspacemagazine/articles*

*Notify change for URI: content://payspace.ssidit.pp.ua.payspacemagazine/articles*

As you can see, uris are equal. Content adds to the database. I don't close a cursor in my code. What can be wrong?

**Update1:**
How I contruct and deal with CursorAdapter.
When the app starts, it calls:

```
mListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.article_list_item, null, from, to, 0);
```

Then I load some data from database. Code of DatabaseCursorLoader:

```
public class DatabaseCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

public static final String LOG_TAG = DatabaseCursorLoader.class.getName();

private int limit;
private Article.Category category;

public DatabaseCursorLoader(Context context, Article.Category category, int limit) {
    super(context);
    this.category = category;
    this.limit = limit;
}

@Override
public Cursor loadInBackground() {
    return getContext().getContentResolver().query(ArticleContract.buildArticlesWithCategoryUri(category), ArticlesDataSource.previewColumns, null, null, Article.KEY_DATE + " DESC LIMIT " + limit);
}
}
```

and swap the cursor:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    int id = loader.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case LOADER_PREVIEWS_DB:
            int loaded = cursor.getCount();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Rows in cursor " + loaded);
            //если мы ничего не загрузили (не осталось новых записей из БД)
            if (loaded - wasLoaded == 0) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Starting service to load new data");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoadPreviewsService.class);
                intent.putExtra(Article.KEY_CATEGORY, mCurrentCategory.ordinal());
                intent.putExtra(Article.KEY_PAGE, mCurrentPage);
                getActivity().startService(intent);
            }
            wasLoaded = loaded;

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Swapped cursor");
            mListAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
            break;
    }

}
```

**Update2:**
The problem was that I've extended CursorLoader class so I think I needed to override some extra methods for correct work. I just changed:

```
loader = new DatabaseCursorLoader(getActivity(), category, page * ARTICLES_PER_PAGE);
```

to

```
loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), ArticleContract.buildArticlesWithCategoryUri(category), ArticlesDataSource.previewColumns, null, null, Article.KEY_DATE + " DESC LIMIT " + (page * ARTICLES_PER_PAGE));
```

and it worked. Big thanks to @pskink!

Comment: are you using a CursorLoader ?

Comment: Maybe, this answer could help you.

[CursorLoader not updating][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915050/cursorloader-not-updating-after-data-change

Comment: Yes, I use CursorLoader, when I restart my app, it displays all loaded contents from database correctly (it loads all content by one query). And I also Log lifecycle of my CursorLoader, it's still working. The problem is that for some reason CursorLoader can't see notifies about updates of database.

Comment: Thanks for the link to post. According to post, I need to check if I have getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null) and setNotificationUri(ContentResolver cr, Uri uri). But I have both of them.

Comment: how do you construct your CursorAdapter?

Comment: @pskink read the update1 please

Comment: any reason for `DatabaseCursorLoader` ? why dont you use `CursorLoader` directly?

Comment: @pskink no reasons :) Earlier I used new class, because it didn't use ContentProvider. I changed it to loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), ArticleContract.buildArticlesWithCategoryUri(category), ArticlesDataSource.previewColumns, null, null, Article.KEY_DATE + " DESC LIMIT " + (page * ARTICLES_PER_PAGE)); and it worked!!! You made my day! Thank you very much. I've been dealing with this problem for about 2 hours.

Comment: no prob, you owe me two Оболонь beers